# What are some places to publish pedagogical articles about teaching undergraduate mathematics?

Tags: undergraduate-education, mathematical-pedagogy, publishing

I've been looking for possible journals to publish an article about undergraduate mathematics pedagogy.   A lot of math journals apparently don't publish articles about pedagogy, or require pedagogical articles to be illuminating some new aspect of math content.

So far, here's what i've found:
http://www.tandfonline.com/toc/upri20/current
http://sigmaa.maa.org/rume/journals.html
http://www.editorialmanager.com/rund/default.asp

For those of  you who do research in undergraduate mathematics education - where have you published things?  For those of you who teach undergraduate mathematics, where do you go to get new ideas about teaching?

Comment: I like your name, it's a good start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The links you've already provided (especially the second one) are quite good.

The top journal, I'd say, is the *Journal for Research in Mathematics Education (JRME)*.

Depending on the content of what you wish to publish, it may be that a journal about education (not specific to mathematics) or one about psychology or cognitive studies (again, not specific to mathematics education) would be viable.

One option would be to look at where prominent mathematics educators have published; for example, you can find some of A Schoenfeld's recent publications [here](http://gse.berkeley.edu/people/alan-h-schoenfeld#user_user_full_group_research); some of D Ball's publications [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~dball/background/DBall_cv_may2014.pdf) (CV pdf); or, more generally, by searching for individuals on Google Scholar.

A lesser known option is the *Journal of Mathematics Education at Teachers College (JMETC)*. The next issue has as its focus post-secondary education, so it may be a good fit for an article on undergraduate mathematics pedagogy. A link to the *JMETC* page can be found [here](http://journals.tc-library.org/index.php/matheducation/).

I might note that, despite its relative newness, the *JMETC* has featured some well-known names in mathematics education: H Burkhardt, HP Ginsburg, C Greenes, J Kilpatrick, HO Pollak, A Schoenfeld, E Silver, WF Tate, U Treisman, and HH Wu.

I have listed some of these individuals' names, since they are generally good people to search for in order to see where else they have published recently.

(As for my own reading: I really like *Math Horizons* and the *American Mathematical Monthly*; I think the *Mathematics Teacher* is a good education-specific choice, too.)

Comment: There's really two separate questions here - where to publish that one's department will recognize as a top-tier journal, and where to publish such that people actually teaching these mathematics courses will read it and decide to try my ideas out in their classes.   JRME clearly fits into the former, but not really the latter.

Comment: @JamesS. True, and by suggesting you look at prominent math educators' choice locations, I have pointed you mostly to department-recognized journals (e.g., ones that would provide a significant boost towards gaining tenure). A journal like *JMETC* or even the NCTM published *Mathematics Teacher* will do little in this respect. As a side-note: It is my hope that one place where teachers will read about ideas and give them a shot in practice is **here** on MESE. The site is still new, but I think it is an important goal to keep in mind as MESE develops...

Answer (score 5):

As for who will publish undergraduate math research, I suggest that [Educational Studies in Mathematics](http://www.springer.com/education+&+language/mathematics+education/journal/10649) is influential in math education research, and will publish research at the undergraduate level. A member of my dissertation committee recently published a study of the concept of limit in an undergraduate mathematics classroom there.

I am not sure what journals people are most likely to go to to inform their undergraduate mathematics instructor practice, but here are some practitioner journals that focus on undergraduate mathematics teaching:

- [The College Mathematics Journal](http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/college-mathematics-journal/the-college-mathematics-journal) an MAA publication (Apparently they have some rules about articles that are purely pedagogical.)
- [Mathematics Teacher](http://www.nctm.org/publications/toc.aspx?jrnl=mt) extends into undergraduate mathematics

Comment: The College Mathematics Journal doesn't publish articles that are on pedagogy, even though their guidelines suggest otherwise...

Comment: How did you find this out? Do they have a stricter policy somewhere, or do they interpret pedagogy literally? Technically, I guess college level pedagogy is andragogy?

Comment: I emailed them over the weekend, and they replied saying that their policy "is not to consider 'pure' pedagogy pieces, but encourage pedagogy discussions as appropriate in articles with some sort of new math content."

Comment: That's... odd. As if we've conquered the teaching of all existing mathematics content.

Comment: I think what they mean is they want a new angle on the content, not merely a new way to teach an existing topic.   Such as: "I've discovered a new property of prime numbers, and here's how I taught it to my number theory students" - rather than: "I've come up with a new way of teaching the standard algorithm for prime factorization..."